# Error : "User not found" with Firebase authentication freezes the app Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword` if the user isn't registered the app crashes.
I used try and catch to avoid it but seems useless.
The error is always the same also after changed it thousands of times :

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(user-not-found, There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
```

I'm using a `Form` to get user input, maybe this is the problem?
By the way in the code below I inserted email and password manually so I think it doesn't care about `Forms`.
This is the code :

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  showErrDialog(BuildContext context, String err) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Error"),
        content: Text(err),
        actions: <Widget>[
          OutlineButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text("Ok"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<User> signin(
      String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    try {
      UserCredential result =
          await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: email);
      User user = result.user;
      return Future.value(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
      switch (e.code) {
        case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
          showErrDialog(context, e.code);
          break;
        case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
          showErrDialog(context, e.code);
          break;
        case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
          showErrDialog(context, e.code);
          break;
        case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
          showErrDialog(context, e.code);
          break;
        case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
          showErrDialog(context, e.code);
          break;
        case 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED':
          showErrDialog(context, e.code);
          break;
      }
```

Called by :

```
onPressed: () => signin("go@gmail.com", "ciaollllL1", context),
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fix for Error

Firebase has updated their packages and they use different error-codes now. You can use the following function which has new error-codes:

```dart
Future<User> signin(String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  try {
    UserCredential result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: email);
    User user = result.user;
    return Future.value(user);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e.code);
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'invalid-email':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'wrong-password':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'user-not-found':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'user-disabled':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

## Fix for Freezing Problem

The freezing problem is not with your code. The problem is in Visual Studio Code. VSCode automatically adds a breakpoint when there are `Uncaught Exceptions`. To disable this follow the steps:

- Go to Run Tab from sidemenu
  [image]
- In Breakpoints, disable `Uncaught Exceptions` under `Breakpoints` section.

[image: Disable Uncaught Exceptions in VSCode]

Comment: Very useful! Thank you mate.

Comment: This is not working. This is working for the old version but with the new version this is not working, Please help me with the new. I have used almost every search but still not getting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

did you give permission in firebase console and also have you added SHA-1 key in in firebase console  [image]

Comment: Sure, but it worked before...I had some users registered but now I changed the code and lost previous version so I don't know whats's happening...yes SHA-1 key is present